# Change color with flutter variable

Tags: flutter

there are two colors that need to be changed from the colors used in my project. These colors will change according to the theme and the theme data will be taken from the API. The problem now is that I manually give the theme to the test variable instead of the api, but the value I give to the int does not change afterwards. Whatever I give to the int at the beginning, it stays.
constant.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

int koyuMor = 0xff410657;
int acikMor = 0xff5B336A;
int lacivert = 0xff0D1665;
int mavi = 0xff009DA4;
int koyuYesil = 0xff055511;
int acikYesil = 0xff8DA637;
int koyuTuruncu = 0xffC83232;
int acikTuruncu = 0xffDB7439;
var theme = 'ocean - theme';
int _color1 = 0;
int _color2 = 0;

void main() {
  if (theme == 'thinker-theme') {
    _color1 = koyuMor;
    _color2 = acikMor;
  }
  if (theme == 'ocean-theme') {
    _color1 = lacivert;
    _color2 = mavi;
  }
  if (theme == 'forest-theme') {
    _color1 = koyuYesil;
    _color2 = acikYesil;
  }
  if (theme == 'sand-theme') {
    _color1 = koyuTuruncu;
    _color2 = acikYesil;
  }
}

class Constant {
  /// [Colors]
  static Color color1 = Color(_color1);
  static final Color color2 = Color(_color2);
  static const Color koyuMor = Color(0x00410657);
  static const Color acikMor = Color(0xff5B336A);
  static const Color mavi = Color(0xff009DA4);
  static const Color lacivert = Color(0xff0D1665);
  static const Color koyuYesil = Color(0xff055511);
  static const Color acikYesil = Color(0xff8DA637);
  static const Color koyuTuruncu = Color(0xffC83232);
  static const Color acikTuruncu = Color(0xffDB7439);
}
```

I also tried with ThemeData, it didn't seem possible to change it later.

the code i use in other pages:

```
color: Constant.color2,
```

edit: sample widget

```
appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Constant.color1,
        title: Text('Anasayfa'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications_none),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
Notifications()));
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.chat),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
Messages()));
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
```

and

```
body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
          Container(
            color: Constant.color2,
            child: Column(
```

Comment: can you include sample widget how you are chaning on widget

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I included it as an edit.

Comment: I mean the place you are changing color  & `ThemeData, it didn't seem possible to change it later` is possible

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I tried it according to the sources I could find, I removed it later because it would work according to the predetermined colors and would make the code too long.

Comment: Make sure to call setState after changing the data-type this is all i can say